# Retrieve data of the the logged in user from database (Android-PHP)

Tags: php, android

I want to get the username from the textfield of the android application and send it to php where i can use it in `$query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM accountmanagers WHERE username = '" . $username. "'");`

Thankyou in advance!

Comment: $username should be the session from the logged-in user, right?

Comment: You need to create token based system. Once you authenticate the user you need to send token to android app. This token then needs to be sent with every request to the php server to uniquely identify the user.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simply return user information from API when they successfully logged in, then save the user information in Shared Preferences, RoomDB, SQLite Etc. This is the best way.

Simply follow this step:

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE user_id = '$user_id' ";   
$response = mysqli_query($connection,$select);
$exist  = mysqli_num_rows($response);


if(!$exist > 0)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO user_info (user_id, user_name, profile, user_token, status, last_online)
     VALUES ('$user_id', '$user_name', '$imageStore', '$user_token', '$status', '$last_online')";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

    if($result){
        $select = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE user_id = '$user_id' ";   

        $response = mysqli_query($connection,$select);

          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){

                $index['user_name'] = $row['2'];
                $index['profile'] = $row['3'];
                $index['status'] = 'success';
                echo json_encode($index);
            }
        
        /* echo json_encode('success'); */
        mysqli_close($connection);
        
        
    }else{
        echo json_encode('failed');
        mysqli_close($connection);
    }
}
else{
    echo json_encode('available');
    mysqli_close($connection);
}
```

Comment: Please, PLEASE use prepared statements. Don't tell people to use code riddled with opportunities for SQL injections. I can't stand it anymore.